# iTerm2 cursor scrolling with mouse enabled in vim

Tags: vim, scroll, iterm2, cursor-position

iTerm2 has a very nice feature that allows, when scrolling the mouse, to move the cursor up and down.

[image]

However, if I enable the mouse in vim with `:set mouse=a`, the scrolling behavior changes: it now scrolls the file but does not move the cursor until the cursor gets out of view.

Is there a way to keep the iTerm2 scrolling along with mouse enabled in vim?

Comment: The same behaviour doesn't happen when you press your up and down arrow keys? Then iTerm does something weird that is not sending the arrow keys.

Comment: The up and down arrow keys still work as expected, i.e. sending the cursor up and down one row.

Comment: Then iTerm2 must be doing something different, otherwise Vim couldn't distinguish between arrow keys and scrolling. You can test this with `cat -v`. To go in alternate screen mode, enter `tput smcup` (when you're done: `tput rmcup`).

Comment: `tput smcup; cat-v` prints the characters corresponding to up and down keys when scrolling. When in vim, `:set mouse=` make the scrolling works, `:set mouse=a` breaks it. Enabling the mouse definitely changes some environment variable or something that makes iTerm2 acts differently.

Comment: you can consider other vim such as mvim or neovim

Comment: @seuling That's not the point :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
map <ScrollWheelDown> j
map <ScrollWheelUp> k
```

Have a look at `:help scroll-mouse-wheel`.

Comment: you probably want `noremap`, and `nnoremap` if it's only for normal mode